# Default shared folder in vagrant not visible

Tags: vagrant

I have a problem with synced folder in Vagrant. My config is really simple:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
end
```

Vagrant usually creates `/vagrant` folder automatically on start - this time it did not happen so I've done it manually.
But when I create a file in my host system - it's not visible in guest. Any ideas why?

I've succesfully created a similar configuration with:

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
```

but it's a little bit outdated and I want to use Ubuntu 16.04.

Is it a problem with my config, vagrant box, or something else?

Comment: you should check why vagrant cannot create the folder, run `vagrant up --debug` the output will be huge but search for `Mounting shared folders...`

Comment: What's this have to do with symlinks btw? Vagrant has some [issues with symbolic links](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) so you should make sure it works with real paths first. You could try adding a synced folder `type`, but you shouldn't have to. Then do a `vagrant reload`.

Comment: @ldg: I'm sorry, there was and ansible plabook attached to this config, but I removed it to make things clear :)

@FrédéricHenri: The output is:
`==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => ~/vagrant_setup`
no errors.

Comment: weird, when you ssh into the vm, `/vagrant` does not appear ?

Comment: After `vagrant up` - no. If I create it manually - yes. But even then it's not shared between host and guest.

Comment: yes you need to mount it from VBoxManage command but its not clear why its not working - do you have long output from `vagrant up --debug`

Comment: I had a similar problem and the solution was to install the Virtualbox Guest Additions plugin: vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest.  Then I did a vagrant up and I was good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try: Make sure you have the latest version of Vagrant and VB. Restart your computer (I know, but it sometimes does help in these cases). Try again in a new directory (or `vagrant destroy` if you want to start fresh and don't need any old content), i.e., make sure the old `.vagrant` directory isn't there.

`vagrant up` or `vagrant reload` and check again.

Assuming you are using VirtualBox, make sure you don't have any "Guest Additions" issues. You could try https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest

If it still doesn't work, check the --debug output again as @frédéric-henri mentioned -- look for all mentions of your share name. Also "/vagrant" isn't always the default, it depends on the box. Sometimes it's "/vagrant_data" or others, but if you specify "/vagrant" in the config -- that should work.

Comment: I did destroy the box and started it up again - still no luck. It's my 3 or 4 attempt.
I'm starting to think it's a problem with this `ubuntu/xenial64` box. Do you know any other boxes with new debian based installation?

Comment: OK, I found the solution. According to: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1565985 this box is broken.

After installing `apt-get --no-install-recommends install virtualbox-guest-utils` shared folder is now visible.

However, this makes no sense to use this box. It has no python (so ansible will not work) and no virtualbox utils forces you to install all of it manually in two steps.

Comment: I used this one for ubuntu 16.04: `geerlingguy/ubuntu1604`

Comment: Thank you - I will check it out :)