# Vagrant synced folder is missing in the guest machine

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm trying to provision a vm with a synced folder to the directory where my `Vagrantfile` resides (should be default behavior, but it's not working). Here is my Vagrantfile in its current state (see `bootstrap.sh` below):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.box_check_update = true

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: 'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX'
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 2]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", 50]
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
end
```

Here is the mount portion of the `vagrant up` output with the `--debug` flag toggled:

```
INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder enable: virtualbox
 INFO interface: output: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: output: ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: detail: /vagrant => /path/to/my/project
 INFO interface: detail:     default: /vagrant => /Users/michaelmartorella/code/ethereum
    default: /vagrant => /path/to/my/project
```

However, when I ssh into the vm, the `/vagrant` directory does not contain the contents of the synced directory on the host machine. I have already tried everything listed in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233531/4942372) and haven't had any luck. I've also tried moving the `config.vm.synced_folder` command below the virtualbox modifications and haven't had any luck there either.

Additionally, if I run `cd /` I don't move to the root directory - it keeps me in the home directory (seems very odd and I assume it's related to whatever is causing this issue).

I'm using:

- `Vagrant 1.9.5`
- `VirtualBox Version 5.1.22`
- `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-119-generic x86_64)`

I'm running this from MacOS Sierra `Version 10.12.5`

---

If it helps, here is my `bootstrap.sh` code as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install git for version control, pip for install python packages
echo "Installing base python requirements..."
sudo apt-get -qq -y install git python-dev build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev libgmp-dev python-pip libssl-dev > /dev/null 2>&1

# Customize the shell
echo "cd() { builtin cd "$@"; ls -FGlAhp; }" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
echo "alias cd..='cd ../'" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
echo "mcd () { mkdir -p "$1" && cd "$1"; }" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
echo "mgrep () { grep -rnIi \"$1\" . --color; }" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
echo "alias geth-init='bash /vagrant/init_geth.sh'" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
echo "alias geth-console='bash /vagrant/geth_console.sh'" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc

# Install ethereum
echo "Installing ethereum..."
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo apt-get update > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo apt-get -y install ethereum > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully installed ethereum!"
else
  echo "Could not install ethereum" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Install pyethapp
echo "Installing pyethapp..."
pip install pyethapp > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully installed pyethapp"
else
  echo "Could not install pyethapp" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Complete
echo ""
echo "Vagrant install complete!"
```

I have no errors with the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue in your `bootstrap.sh` script on this line

```
echo "cd() { builtin cd "$@"; ls -FGlAhp; }" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
```

The special characters need to be escaped, you can verify your `.bashrc` file after provisioning but its not as you have in your shell script; so you should replace with

```
echo "cd() { builtin cd \"\$@\"; ls -FGlAhp; }" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
```

Be careful about escaping, you made it correctly for `mgrep` function but its incorrect for `mcd` so you would need to fix this. Generally verify your `.bashrc` file if you want to make modification through script that the update was done accordingly.